# Fixing navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I've added a navigation bar from "Object Library" below of `UITableViewController`'s navigation bar (Which added with "Embed In" option). And it moves when table scrolling down. How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Can show the image of view so i can see where you have added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot anchor a element in a `UITableViewController`. You can create a main ViewController, embedded in a Navigation Controller, add your Navigation Bar and then add a Container and link it to your `UITableViewController`.

Like this:
[image: Screen of Xcode storyboard]

Comment: Thanks a lot @ale00. But one more question. Now, how I can write action of navigation bar's buttons. Because they were performing some functions on my table after their pressing and now they are in a separate View Controller.